# Error creating foreign key on <table>(check data types)

Tags: sql, database

**Error creating foreign key on local_fees (check data types)**
`I already check my datatypes in both table manage_fees and fees table`

- Already set `fees pk` into unsgined same as the `manage_fee`  im still getting the error message about datatypes
- error that im getting whenever i set `on delete  null`

> ALTER TABLE `manage_fees` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_fees` FOREIGN KEY (`local_fees`) REFERENCES `fees`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

- aside from that whenever i set on delete restrict it works without showing error message.

> ALTER TABLE `manage_fees` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_fees` FOREIGN KEY (`local_fees`) REFERENCES `fees`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

Anyone can help me with my problem?

Comment: Is local_fees nullable? Can you post description of both tables?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KjHMSHks here are my tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply `ON DELETE SET NULL` for `local_fees` because it is not NULLABLE.
If you need to default it to NULL, you should make it nullable:

```
CREATE TABLE `manage_fees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year_lvl` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `semester` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `local_fees` int(11) NULL,
  `time_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
)
```

Comment: oh jeez i thought that wont matter at all because it keeps saying that check on datatypes but now it makes sense already.

Comment: Also is it fine to use `ON DELETE SET NULL` when you want something to delete in your parent table?

Comment: It really depends on your business case. From data integrity point of view, it is fine. From business point of view, I cannot say without understanding your goal.